# Injecting/Including a value for every WriteEvent in SLAB

Tags: enterprise-library, slab

We are using Semantic Logging Application Block (SLAB) and have 300+ logging methods currently.

Is there a way to easily include a value in every single WriteEvent call without having to update all of the logging methods?  E.g. include client's IP address for every single event written to the log.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I can use IEventTextFormatter and inject the value there.